# Passing JSON response into Go template

Tags: go

I'm making a JSON GET request, and I'm now trying to pass the data on to my template to render within the HTML. With Python I could just pass the response straight on, but with Go I'm thinking I need to restructure the JSON using a struct?

```golang
// index route
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        resp, err := http.Get("https://example.com/json")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()

        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        log.Println(string(body))

        err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", body)
        if err != nil {
            panic("Oh no!")
        }
    })
```

Do I need to go through the JSON and manually build a struct to handle it or is there an easy way to just pass the data along?

Comment: `ReadAll` returns a slice of bytes, it has no structure for you to use in or outside of a template. You need to first give the data some structure.

Comment: If the json represented by bytes is arbitrary, you can use a map, if it is a predefined json object with know fields, I'd recommend you use a struct type. If it is an array use a slice of structs or maps. If you don't know whether the json contains an object or an array at the root, you can initialize an empty interface variable and unmarshal the data into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes you would like to pass on the unmarshalled JSON data, rather than the raw blob of data.

You can simply unmarshal the JSON to a `map[string]interface{}`, which you can then pass on to the template.

It will look something like this:

```
var data map[string]interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(rawJSON), &data); err != nil {
    // Handle error.
}

if err := tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil {
    // Handle error.
}
```

Here's [a Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_rGi7uv0Zbq) demonstrating this.